# Formula for the angle bisector length with area and two angles

Tags: triangles, angle, bisection

How can I proof $w_\gamma 
=\dfrac{2F}{c\cos \left(\frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\right)}$ ?

Where $w_\gamma$   is the length of the angle bisector of the side $c$ 
and  $\alpha$, $\beta$ are the angles of the vertices $A$, $B$ 
and $F$ is the area of the triangle.

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Start by drawing a diagram. Also note that $\dfrac {2F}c$ is a height of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Without loss of generality, let's assume that $|AC|>|BC|$.
Then

\begin{align}
\triangle CDH_c:\quad
w_{\gamma}=|CD|
&=
\frac{|CH_c|}{\cos\angle H_cCD}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\\
&=\frac{|CH_c|}{\cos(\tfrac12\gamma-(90^\circ-\beta))}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\\
&=\frac{|CH_c|}{\cos(\tfrac12(180^\circ-\alpha-\beta)-(90^\circ-\beta))}
\tag{3}\label{3}
\\
&=\frac{|CH_c|}{\cos\tfrac{\beta-\alpha}2}
=\frac{|CH_c|}{\cos\tfrac{\alpha-\beta}2}
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

As @player3236 pointed out in a comment,

\begin{align} 
|CH_c|&=\frac{2F}c
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Substitution of \eqref{5} into \eqref{4}
provides the desired result

\begin{align}
w_{\gamma}&=|CD|
=\frac{2F}{c\cdot\cos\tfrac{\alpha-\beta}2}
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Note that since $\cos\tfrac{\alpha-\beta}2=\cos\tfrac{\beta-\alpha}2$,
the expression \eqref{6} holds also if $|AC|<|BC|$,
and it also holds if $|AC|=|BC|$ too.